# Is it ok to delete .hg/store/data/{corrupted-file}.i. from remote mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, repository, clone

We are unable to pull or push due to integrity error on a file. one possible solution is to reclone it but this means, all developers and teamcity have to re-clone this repository.

Can I not just delete that file from repository directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply rename the file (so you are able to restore it).

Afterwards I would do simply:

```
hg update
hg commit
```